# Return result for one-to-many given table B ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know this has probably been answered before, but I apologize as I cannot find the answer that might solve this for me. I have a one-to-many Postgres database where I want to make sure that every row in table A is in the result, as well as a value that is stored in table B, and make sure to also show table A even if table B does not have an entry that links to a row in table A.

Table A:

| tableA_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Row1 |
| 2 | Row2 |
| 3 | Row3 |
| 4 | Row4 |

Table B:

| tableB_id | a_id | user_id | is_subscribed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | true |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | false |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | true |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | false |
| 5 | 4 | 3 | true |

I want a query where I can return the table A entries for each specific user, along with the `is_subscribed` value for each entry, even those which there is not an entry in table B. SO the results would look like this:

(given user Id 1):

| tableA_id | name | is_subscribed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Row1 | true |
| 2 | Row2 | true |
| 3 | Row3 | false |
| 4 | Row4 | null |

I have been able with JOIN tables to get it very close, but I am struggling past the hurdle of returning the 4th row in table A as there is not an entry in table B.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If when you use inner join (join is default - inner join) you will be see this result:

```
tableA_id   name    is_subscribed
1           Row1    true
2           Row2    true
3           Row3    false
```

If when you use left join you will be see this result:

```
tableA_id   name    is_subscribed
1           Row1    true
2           Row2    true
3           Row3    false
4           Row4    null
```

And if you want to see default false when data is not in table_b use this query:

```
select 
    a.tableA_id, 
    a.name, 
    case when b.is_subscribed is null then false else b.is_subscribed end as is_subscribed 
from 
    table_A a
left join 
    table_B b on b.a_id = a.tableA_id and b.user_id = 1


Result: 
tableA_id   name    is_subscribed
1           Row1    true
2           Row2    true
3           Row3    false
4           Row4    false
```

Comment: left join AND user_id = 1 was what did it. I was doing a WHERE. Thank you! I am truly a SQL noob